# SLDS Responsive classes - not quite working?

Tags: slds

According to the salesforce documentation
[image]

my understanding of that is :
**slds-hide_medium** will **hide** content when the breakpoint is true (768px and above) and will therefore **show** content when it is false (less than 768px).

**slds-show-medium** (which I assume is the opposite of **slds-hide_medium**) will **show** content when the breakpoint is true (768px and above) and will therefore **hide** content when it is false (less than 768px)

Righto...
slds-hide_medium works as advertised.
slds-show_medium doesn't

Let's look at this markup :

[image]

and this result (and of course what I want here is either the button OR the image, not both) :

[image]

The result is shown when the screen is **767px**
When the screen is 768px all is well
When the screen is 766px all is well.

The bottom line is **slds-show_medium** is NOT hiding content when the size of the screen is less than the breakpoint (767 is less than 768 right?)

All I'm trying to do is show a **button** when **condition A is true** (desktop stuff) and alternatively, show an **image** when condition A is false (not a desktop), using what I believe are the appropriate tools/classes we have been provided to do this....

This of course is so unimportant it's not really funny, but I'd like to understand if I'm doing something wrong or perhaps the media queries that make all this magic work are messed up a bit somewhere.

I am simulating this 767px thing by very carefully resizing my browser window (in case you were wondering :) )

Comment: It is not really device width but parent container width. If you have device width as 768px but container width of slds-show_medium is 300px, it will hide content. Just make sure what the immediate parent container width is because that drives the behavior of these classes.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. This post was about an 'edge' case where the device width was EXACTLY 767px. Above and below this width, the classes behave exactly as expected. Your understanding (and explanation) of how media queries currently work is unfortunately completely incorrect. The concept of container width queries simply does not exist (at present). This may help you for future reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries